# Azure search portal does not allow anymore to click on a particular index name and look at index details like schema etc

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

[Azure Search portal index dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOws3.png)

Earlier when I used to go to Azure search portal dashboard, I would see list of indexes and I was able to click on each index and was able to see the index details like schema.

Now for the indexes which I have created there is no way in the portal to get the schema of it as the clicking on index name is no longer working.

Is it a bug or an intended change inside azure search dashboard page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a change from the Portal Framework team.
As a work-around, try the following:

1. Go to the regular portal via incognito browser (prevents using cached info)
2. Use this url: https://portal.azure.com/?feature.customportal=false.
   This is the public portal which theoretically shouldn't have the bad changes (note the `feature.customportal-false` flag).

Comment: Thanks!! I got it working with the steps you gave. By default, Azure portal framework team is planning to disable this feature which allows users to see schema on azure portal? or  was it unintended consequence of some other change?